# DataGridView KeyDown manipulation (enter, left, right, etc.) not working when multiselect

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, multi-select

I want to make the `DataGridView` more handy while manipulating the `KeyDown` event, like the `KeyEnter` for moving one cell to the right, or using left, down or up. I have some special use cases where I want to check first the cell and depending on that I can discard this event for example or point it to an another cell. This is working fine until I set the "multiselect" feature to true. Then the complete process of leaving focus and set the right focus, per cell is not working fine anymore. Please find some sample code below:

```
private bool GridNavigation(Keys keys)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (keys == Keys.Enter || keys == Keys.Right)
        {
                for (int i = iColumn + 1; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 4; i++)
                {
                    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].ReadOnly)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].Selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 4 && dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 != iRow)
                    {
                        if (((IDictionary<int, int>)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Tag).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == (int)clsDefinitions.ZeilenIndikator.Typ).Value == (int)clsDefinitions.ZeilenTyp.PassLängeAusgangswert)
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 2];
                        else
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
                        return true;
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (keys == Keys.Left)
        {
            for (int i = iColumn - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (!dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].ReadOnly)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter || keyData == Keys.Right || keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            return GridNavigation(keyData);
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

So what can be done here. You can easily reproduce by open a new Project and just put a `DataGridView` in the form and add for example 10 columns or more.

If there's something else I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: Is there anything special about `if (((IDictionary<int, int>)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Tag).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == (int)clsDefinitions.ZeilenIndikator.Typ).Value == (int)clsDefinitions.ZeilenTyp.PassLängeAusgangswert)` we need to know when reproducing your output?

Comment: Nope, nothing really special. It checks if the row has a special flag set which is stored under a Row.Tag. So in case there is a special Tag for example the one you mentioned it will jump two rows instead of one row. But this should not really make a difference for the issue I described. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `GridNavigation` method, under both conditions, `if (keys == Keys.Enter || keys == Keys.Right)` and `else if (keys == Keys.Left)`, the guilty party here is the recurring line:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].Selected = true;
```

**What went wrong?**

When `dataGridView1.MultiSelect == false` the above line effectively sets the current cell, not just the `Selected` property. I.E:

1. `CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[0]`, `Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true`
2. User clicks <kbd>`->`</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - `Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true`
   - `CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[1]`
   - `Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false`

However, when `dataGridView1.MultiSelect == true` the same line of code does *not* set the current cell.  So the current cell remains selected as well as the adjoining cell to the left or right respectively. I.E:

1. `CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[0]`, `Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true`
2. User clicks <kbd>`->`</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - `Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true`
   - `CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[0]`
   - `Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true`
3. User again clicks <kbd>`->`</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - Expected results: `Rows[0].Cells[2].Selected = true`.
   - Actual results: `Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true` ...again.

**Solution**

If you want it to behave the same as `MultiSelect = false` and only have *one* selected cell when you navigate left or right, just replace the guilty lines of code with:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells[i];
```

If you want to retain the previously selected cells, replace the guilty lines of code with:

```
DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection cells = dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[i];

if (dataGridView1.MultiSelect)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
  {
    cell.Selected = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I got it working with your help. Many Many Thanks for your quick response and with your very details explanation. Impressive !

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the selection mode?

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
```